# How to use Mapbox Mapmatching API output with mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am quite new to this , really  need guidance,

I understand that with Mapbox Map Matching API, i will get the raw out put of correct location, but what I dont understand, how can i use mapbox map-matching API output with  mapbox-gl-js to create correct map?

Do i need to use mapbox-match-js for this ?  if yes , how do i pass the geo json?

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-match.js/tree/master

```
L.mapbox.mapmatching(geojson, options, function (error, layer) {
    layer.addTo(map);
    layer.setStyle({
        color: '#9a0202',
        weight: 4,
        opacity: 0.8
    });
});
```

there is a demo html here, but the raw out put is not same as map-matching API out put,

Can any one please help me with this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi
any one can help me with this ?
i just wanted to know, how shall i use mapbox mapmatch API with mapbox.GL 

Please give me some light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is my solution:

1) Add  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/mapbox@1.0.0-beta7/dist/mapbox-sdk.js"></script>` in my `index.html` file.

2) Use mapbox.matching:

```
var mapboxClient = new MapboxClient(mapboxgl.accessToken);
mapboxClient.matching(
// dataToAddLine: array like:  
// [
//    [13.418805122375488, 52.50059890747071],
//    [13.419144630432129, 52.50109481811523]
// ]
  dataToAddLine.features[0].geometry.coordinates
  , function(err, res) {
 // do something with res
   console.log(res);
  }
```

)

You can test res coordinates here: [geojson](http://geojson.io/#map=17/45.51627/9.17362)

I hope this solution helps you too.